# Are any of these airline "secrets" true?

Tags: safety, airline-operations

I have recently seen a list of things that are not known by passengers of planes. It was found on a site where you have to recheck and double-check everything, but besides obviously wrong facts there are some that I would like to clarify. They are

1. Often corpse of dead people are transported as the cargo during regular flights.
2. If the plane lands at night, the lights in the cabin are low, so if the passengers have to evac, their eyes are used to darkness.
3. The pilots are given different food and must not share it among the crew.
4. The headphones passengers recieve are in fact used multiple times.

Which of the facts are true?

Comment: #2: [Why are cabin lights turned off during takeoff/landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8471/why-are-the-lights-inside-commercial-airplanes-turned-off-during-take-off-and-la)

Comment: #3: [Is it true that the pilot and copilot are required to eat different meals?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/555/is-it-true-that-the-pilot-and-co-pilot-are-required-to-eat-different-meals)

Comment: You can see we already have a couple of those addressed on the site. It would be better to ask them separately. The headphones question would probably be better asked on Travel.SE.

Comment: @RonBeyer should I delete these parts of the question?

Comment: See also [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50271/62) for number 1, and [this very interesting answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/49145/62)

Comment: This is too broad. The Stack Exchange format just doesn't work when multiple unrelated questions get lumped together.

Comment: Examples of #1: [UA](https://www.unitedcargo.com/shipping/productsAndShipping.jsp?name=TrustUA&type=product), [DL](https://www.deltacargo.com/Cargo/catalog/products/delta-cares), [AA](https://www.aacargo.com/learn/humanremains.html) , [List of a bunch of carriers](http://www.nfda.org/resources/operations-management/shipping-remains/airline-requirements)

Comment: Downvoted because the claim that these things are "not known".  Now there may be some totally oblivious people who don't realize those are probably commonplace (except #3 - but I'd expect the pilots' union might have something to say about requiring their members to eat standard airline fare :-)), but I'd expect most people would, if they bothered to think about them at all.

Comment: what have these (esp. 1 and 4) to do with safety anyway? Unless you're afraid the dead will rise and turn everyone on board into zombies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most of these have been answered already, so if you're looking for a brief summary:

1. "Often" is an overstatement, just sometimes. But dying is part of being human, and not everyone does it within driving distance of their family. Death just means you can't self-load, flying's still on the table.
2. Yes.
3. Sometimes. The meals are normal J/F, not anything special though. The answer linked in comments offers the details.
4. Sometimes. Not the cheap all hard plastic ones.

---

P.S. Calling this "secrets" that someone "keeps" from anyone is tabloid clickbaiting. You'll find most of them in official documents and on public websites. I suppose "things you never cared to know, so never bothered to ask" wouldn't have grabbed as much attention...